# A word to describe an event that brings out one’s true character

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I’m looking for a word or a phrase that sums up an event that causes someone to be tested, or something that reveals one’s true character.

Comment: Something like "moment of truth"?

Comment: **Seminal moment**: "While there, she had a seminal moment that turned her to feminism and inspired her to take up performing."

Comment: @Jim Mack I think that's spot on. And far better than anything else I can think of.  It needs an 'answer' with a linked/attributed supporting reference.

Comment: An everyday idiom is to say someone was "in their element". Jack likes dogs, and his parents take him to visit some people who have four. They may remark "Jack is in his element, with all those canines".

Answer (score 5):

"**Defining moment**" maybe.

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/defining-moment?s=t):
a point at which the essential nature or character of a person, group, etc., is revealed or identified.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/defining_moment):
An event which typifies or determines all subsequent related occurrences.

One of Lexico's examples is:
*‘Both of those events were defining moments in my life.’*
Though I guess if you have *two* such events the second would be a **redefining** moment.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you're looking for **hour of reckoning**

> the moment of truth : the time when something would be decided

*The hour of reckoning had come.*

[Merriam-Webster]

Or perhaps **litmus test**

> If you say that something is a litmus test of something, you mean that it is an effective and definite way of proving it or measuring it

*Ending the fighting must be the absolute priority, the litmus test of the agreements' validity.*

[Collins]

Answer (score 4):

I suggested the phrase "moment of truth" in a comment. Fleshing that out, the phrase may originate in bullfighting (Spanish *el momento de verdad*). In any case [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/moment+of+truth) has the following:

> 1. A critical or decisive time on which much depends; a crucial moment.
> 2. Sports The point in a bullfight at which the matador makes the kill.

Also from the TFD link:

> 2. the moment at which one's character, courage, skill, etc., is put to an extreme test; critical moment.

Answer (score 2):

The adjective "telling" does characterize an action or event in the specified way; however, you have to mention the particular thing that is revealed through the given action (character, determination, skill, etc.). There does not seem to exist a one word term for that.

- The last competition was a **telling** event as regards his character.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase which comes directly to my mind is "**A Test of Fire**" but I could not find a [formal definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=test%20of%20fire%20meaning) although I do see it being [in usage](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22test%20of%20fire%22&tbm=bks). A close relative would be "Trial By Fire"

From the [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trial_by_fire):

> A test in which a person is exposed to flames in order to assess their truthfulness, commitment, courage, etc.
>
> A situation in which a
> soldier or other combatant faces the discharge of opposing weapons, as a test of their fortitude.  (idiomatic, by extension)
>
> Any ordeal which tests one's strength, endurance, or resolve.

Answer (score -1):

**An everyday idiom is to say someone was "in their element".**

Jack likes dogs, and his parents take him to visit some people who have four. They may remark "Jack is in his element, with all those canines".

This is confirmed by the Oxford English Dictionary. Sense 12 of ***element*** indicates a figurative use.

> 12. That one of the ‘four elements’ which is the natural abode of any particular class of living beings; said chiefly of air and water.
>     Hence transferred and figurative (a person's) ordinary range of
>     activity, the surroundings in which one feels at home; the appropriate
>     sphere of operation of any agency. **Phrases, in, out of (one's)
>     element.**

It would appear to date from roughly the time of Shakespeare - the first example being from 1599.

> 1599   Master Broughtons Lett. Answered viii. 26   You are in for all
> day..it is your element.

More recent entries are from the 19th century - but the expression is certainly alive and well today.

> 1849   T. B. Macaulay Hist. Eng. I. 534   Ferguson was in his element.
>
> 1874   F. D. Maurice Friendship Bks. iii. 69   Englishmen were to be
> taught that..the sea was to be their element.
>
> 1891   N.E.D. at Element   Mod. Some fishes can live a long time after
> removal from their element.

Comment: If you're in your element, you're content, at ease. Few would say your mettle is being tested in such circumstances. Will have to downvote soon.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The OED seems to confirm my understanding of how the expression is used, when it talks about "usual range of activity". To my mind, if somone is in their element, they are in a milieu where a favourite occupation, or entertainment is on offer. See what others think.